# get process(e.g. TextEdit) as an object in cocoa

Tags: cocoa, process, object

I am a newbie and i want to get a process or a key window as an object as i need to send message to it.In fact , i need to get them so that i can manipulate them with my input method kid(IMKit). 
The corresponding method is:

```
-(BOOL)inputText:key:modifiers:client:
```

I want the key window/process receive the event as client.
I am appreciated if anyone can help.

Answer (score 0):

> i want to get a process or a key window as an object as i need to send message to it. … the corresponding method is
>
> ```
> -(BOOL)inputText:key:modifiers:client:
> ```

You have it the wrong way around. As noted in [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/IMKServerInput_Additions/Reference/IMKServerInput.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/inputText:key:modifiers:client:), that method is one that *you* implement, in your input method. Your input method does not send that message; it receives it. And all you do in that method is accept or veto the input.

I think you need to post a higher-level question about whatever it is you're trying to do, asking how to do it.